# How does Spring MVC relate to Service, Controller and Data Access layers in a web application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller, service

I understand the [MVC Pattern](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/mvc_pattern.htm) and also how [Spring MVC](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_web_mvc_framework.htm) implements it.

However, how do the `Rest controller`, `Data Access Layer` and `Service Layer` fit into this pattern?

Is it:

- **Model** = Database (e.g. Oracle/MySQL) and [Repositories](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.6.1.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html) classes
- **Controller** = `Service` (buisness logic) and Rest `Controller` classes
- **View** = `JSP` / `FreeMarker`?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**Model** - is not a Database, is not a Repositories, is not an Entity. Model is abstraction, that contains all data, that is needed to be displayed. And every `View` has it's own model. You can consider `Model` as *container for data* between `Controller` and `View`.

In Spring model is `ModelMap` parameter of method of controller.

**Controller** - prepares `Model`, to pass it to `View`. If model is quite simple, `Controller` can do it by itself.

But most of models contains a lot of data. This can be multiple Entities from database, data from configuration etc. In this case Controller use lower level tier: `Service`, `Repository`. They all help the `Сontroller` to build model for `View`.

**upd:** It is a purpose of `Controller` to connect `View` and `Model`. `Controller` creates and fills the `Model`, then chooses `View` and pass this created `Model` to the `View`. *That's how Model and View get connection*.

In Spring controllers are `Controller` and `RestController`.

**View** - is final point where data from `Model` (passed by `Controller`) will be displayed to user. But another role of `View` is get commands from user, and pass it to `Controller`.

In Spring this may be view of any view-engine: `JSP`,`Freemaker`,`Thymeleaf`.

---

Note: usually, `Controller` does not use `Repository` directly. Traditionally, `Controller` works with `Service`, and `Service` uses `Repository` to get data from database. So relations are following: `View`<-`Controller`->`Service`->`Repository`

Comment: Thank you for a very detailed answer. I understand almost all apart from how the Model and View are connected? Does the service class alter the model which then alters the view? Can you please expand on the: Controller->Service->Repository to include the view?

Comment: Service knows nothing about Model and View. 
Only Controller knows all. Main Controller's purpose is connect all components with each other. Only Controller can change the Model. Only Controller can ask the Service to do something. For example, controller can ask the Service to load Entity from database. After that Controller will add this Enitity (or multiple Entities) to Model and will pass this Model to View. And View will show this Model, but View even has no idea, where from Controller get data that stored in Model.

Comment: As well as Service does not know what for Controller get data. So it provides less dependencies between components.

Comment: Ok thanks. So essentially is it: CONTROLLER > SERVICE > REPOSITORY/MODEL > VIEW ? Then the view will be passed to the browser to be shown?

Comment: Model is not Entity? This is confusing. I have been learning Model = Pojo = Entity all time. Could you please clarify?

Comment: @Pawan In academical terms you're right - entity is the model. But actually in terms of Spring entity just a part of the model. Model is collection of entities, variables and any data, that view need to show.

Answer (score 7):

A controller accepts HTTP requests and often loads or save some data (from a service or DAO), and return an HTTP response. This response could be a redirect, or a view, or some JSON or a binary file.

A controller can use services, but should avoid having much logic of its own. It can also directly use data access objects, if there's no service logic required.

The model is whatever info a view needs to do its job. It is not necessarily related to a database. For example, you could have a model in a registration form, with email address and confirmEmailAddress fields. You don't store a confirmEmailAddress field in your db, so they there is not a 1-to-1 relationship between db tables and models. Also, your model could be data for a simple calculation that is not persisted.

Comment: "The model is whatever info a view needs to do its job" - Can you please expand on this? Also, if you are including a Spring Data Reposiory in your application, i assume it will be seen as the Model layer? Thanks for your answer

Comment: Model is just a map of objects. These objects may or may not be entities. If you're using Spring Data, then yes, you'd likely add a list of entities to your model, but you could add other stuff too, like data for a drop down, all in the same model.

Comment: Thank you that is starting to make sense, in terms of the view is it essentially JSP or something similar? I also wonder how the view in MVC links to the actual page on the browser that the user views?

Comment: @java123999 The View layer can be one of a few things. JSP is one type. Thymeleaf is another. JasperReports is another. It should be a reasonably dumb layer that just displays data.

Comment: thanks, Javascript on the browser is not related to this view at all?

Comment: @java123999 using AJAX complicates things, as you might get data from several requests. My answer is most applicable to server-generated HTML

Answer (score 1):

So let me make sure I understand ...

The user interacts with an interface to view or submit data. The user calls on the interface to view some data. That call (an HTTP Request) goes to the Dispatcher Servlet (DS).

The DS then consults the handler mapping to help it decide which Controller to use.

Once chosen, the DS passes the request onto the Controller which calls the appropriate service methods, based on GET or POST. The Service method may need to interact with a Repository, which can interact with non-volatile storage (database, XML file, text file, etc), to construct a model based on defined business logic. Once complete, the model data is returned to the DS.

The DS then consults the View Resolver on which view should be used. The View Resolver picks a defined view for the request.

The DS then forwards the request onto the View, which is presented to the user.